# What causes /proc/<pid>/* resources to become owned by root, despite the procs being launched as a normal user?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, proc

I've noticed that some procs, such as bash, have their entire `/proc/<pid>/` resources readable by the user who created that proc. However other procs, such as chrome or gnome-keyring-daemon, have most of their `/proc/<pid>/` resources only accessible by root, despite the process itself being owned by the normal user and no suid being called.

I dug through the kernel a bit and found that the /proc/ stuff gets limited if a task lacks a 'dumpable' flag, however I'm having a hard time understanding under what scenarios a task becomes undumpable (other than the setuid case, which doesn't apply to chrome or gnome-keyring):

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/164c09978cebebd8b5fc198e9243777dbaecdfa0/fs/proc/base.c#L1532

Anyone care to help me understand the underlying mechanism and the reasons for it?

Thanks!

Edit:

Found a good doc on why you wouldn't want to have your SSH agent (such as `gnome-keyring-daemon`) dumpable by your user. Still not sure *how* `gnome-keyring-daemon` is making itself undumpable.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/164c09978cebebd8b5fc198e9243777dbaecdfa0/Documentation/security/Yama.txt#L30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux has a system call, which will change the `dumpable` flag. Here is some example code, which [I wrote](http://kasperd.net/~kasperd/comp.os.linux.development.faq#suidcore) several years ago:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
...
/* The last three arguments are just padding, because the
 * system call requires five arguments.
 */
prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE,1,42,42,42);
```

It may be that `gnome-keyring-daemon` deliberately set the `dumpable` flag to zero for security reasons.

Comment: Such a call should show up in strace, correct? All I'm seeing in there is a prctl to PR_SET_NAME.

Comment: On a side note, regarding your post from several years ago, I believe you can set the `fs.suid_dumpable` sysctl to `2` to allow setuid binaries to become dumpable.

Comment: The dumpable behaviour doesn't just apply to setuid binaries, but setcap binaries too. Try running `getcap /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon`. Its probably got some file capabilities on it.

Comment: This is what `getcap` says on Ubuntu 12.04: `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon = cap_ipc_lock+ep`

Comment: Then it has capabilities to lock memory and thus disables the dumpable flag.